# aws glue logs: naming convention

Tags: logging, aws-glue

I would like to understand how glue jobs log's files names are created/assigned. For the same job (name) I get completely different log's files names with each execution, even for the same day, with no apparent connection (among file's names).

Is there something like [account_id]+[virt_machine_id]+[glue-job-name]+[year]+[month]+[day]+[HHMMSS] so that I can know in "advance" how can I identify all logs generated by the same glue job (name)? and the previous with a common year of execution? and the previous with a common month? things like that.